# Aligning images and text vertically in css

Tags: html, css

I have a screenshot which I have replicated in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rzx731r/13/embedded/result/). At this moment, I am able to replicate everything but **images and text are still need to be aligned vertically in one column**.

[image]

The snippets of HTML code in order to replicate the screenshot are:

```
<div class="achievement1">
    <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7492" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118">
    <a style="color: black;" href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/9928-steve-cody-the-better-software-company.html">"How I Turned $1,200 into Multi-Million Dollar Businesses"</a>
    <a href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/">- Business News Daily</a>
</div>
```

I have made a parent div achievements class in which I have placed three child achievements div class.

**Problem Statement:** I am wondering what CSS codes I should add in the CSS section so that text comes in column and images come in another column as shown in the screenshot.

I tried with **display: inline-block** and **display:block** but still I wasn't able to place images and text in one column.

Comment: you should try `display: flex`

Comment: None of the tens of solutions I found searching SO worked for you?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this it's supported by most browsers:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
}

.achievement3,
.achievement2,
.achievement1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="achievements">
    <div class="achievement1">
      <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7492" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118"><br> <a style="color: black;" href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/9928-steve-cody-the-better-software-company.html">"How I Turned $1,200 into Multi-Million Dollar Businesses"</a><br>      <a href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/">- Business News Daily</a>
    </div>
    <div class="achievement2">
      <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7501" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118"><br> <a style="color: black;" href="https://www.globalfranchisemagazine.com/advice/case-study/revolutionize-your-franchising">"Revolutionize Your Franchise "</a><br>      <a href="https://www.globalfranchisemagazine.com/">- Global Franchise Magazine</a>
    </div>
    <div class="achievement3">
      <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7492" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118"><br> <a style="color: black;" href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/9928-steve-cody-the-better-software-company.html">"Introduces Franchise Community to BPro Platform"</a><br>      <a href="http://www.franchiseharbor.com/">- Franchise Harbor</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS Flexbox** and valid markup you can do this easily

```css
  .achievement1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.caption {
  margin-left: 30px;}
  .caption a {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom:5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="achievement1">
  <div class="figure">
    <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7492" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118"></div>
  <div class="caption">
    <a style="color: black;" href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/9928-steve-cody-the-better-software-company.html">"How I Turned $1,200 into Multi-Million Dollar Businesses"</a>
    <a href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/">- Business News Daily</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your css:

```
.achievement1,
.achievement2,
.achievement3 {
   display: flex;
   align-items:center;
}
```

In your snippets, remove the `br` after the `image` element and add a div to wrap your text

```
<div class="achievement1">
    <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7492" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118">
        <div>
            <a style="color: black;" href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/9928-steve-cody-the-better-software-company.html">"How I Turned $1,200 into Multi-Million Dollar Businesses"</a>
            <a href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/">- Business News Daily</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0rzx731r/16/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't add styling to the `alignleft` class that is in the `img` tag. Add `float: left` to that class and it works.

```css
.achievement1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="achievements">
<div class="achievement1">
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7492" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118"><a style="color: black;" href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/9928-steve-cody-the-better-software-company.html">"How I Turned $1,200 into Multi-Million Dollar Businesses"</a><br> <a href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/">- Business News Daily</a>
</div>
<div class="achievement1">
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7501" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118"><a style="color: black;" href="https://www.globalfranchisemagazine.com/advice/case-study/revolutionize-your-franchising">"Revolutionize Your Franchise "</a><br> <a href="https://www.globalfranchisemagazine.com/">- Global Franchise Magazine</a>
</div>
<div class="achievement1">
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7492" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118"><a style="color: black;" href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/9928-steve-cody-the-better-software-company.html">"Introduces Franchise Community to BPro Platform"</a><br> <a href="http://www.franchiseharbor.com/">- Franchise Harbor</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Since you are already using bootstrap, you can make use of bootstrap's grid system which makes it easier.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="achievements">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7492" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118"></div>
<div class="col-sm-9"><a style="color: black;" href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/9928-steve-cody-the-better-software-company.html">"How I Turned $1,200 into Multi-Million Dollar Businesses"</a><br> <a href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/">- Business News Daily</a></div>
</div>
</br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7492" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118"></div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<a style="color: black;" href="https://www.globalfranchisemagazine.com/advice/case-study/revolutionize-your-franchising">"Revolutionize Your Franchise "</a><br> <a href="https://www.globalfranchisemagazine.com/">- Global Franchise Magazine</a></div>
</div>
</br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7492" src="https://s31.postimg.cc/3nkv5hy7f/rsz_31944265_10214037958016144_5257718905849249792_n.png" alt="" width="161" height="118"></div>
<div class="col-sm-9"><a style="color: black;" href="https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/9928-steve-cody-the-better-software-company.html">"Introduces Franchise Community to BPro Platform"</a><br> <a href="http://www.franchiseharbor.com/">- Franchise Harbor</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```